# Why fflush(stdin) does not remove buffer (stdin)

Tags: c, macos

I have a test code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char c, str[20];
    printf("Enter a character : ");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf("Enter a string : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(str);
    printf("\n\n\nResult : %c\n%s\n", c, str);
    return 0;
}
```

I've read some articles said that this code will work because after scanning the c character, there is still '\n' character in the buffer. The fflush(stdin) will clear the buffer, so gets() function can work properly

But in fact, when I compile and run this code in Mac OS environment, fflush(stdin) do nothing. I entered a character (for ex, 'k'), then it print the k character and a '\n' character. It supposes to allow me to enter a character, a string and then print both of them. Anyone know why?
Thanks!

Comment: `The fflush(stdin) will clear the buffer` is wrong. fflush is for output streams only.

Comment: Did you have a look at the "Questions that may already have your answer" before hitting the "Post your Question" button?

Comment: By implementation of the processing system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) is documented as working on *output* streams, not on input ones.

> The standards do not specify the behavior for input streams.

In particular [POSIX specification for `fflush`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/fflush.html) don't mention input streams.
So it is probably an [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) from the POSIX point of view.

However, on Linux `fflush(stdin)` is possible (but I don't recommend it) since

> For input streams associated with *seekable* files (e.g., disk files,
>     but not pipes or terminals), `fflush()` discards any buffered data that
>     has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed
>     by the application.
>
> For input streams, fflush() discards any
>          buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has
>          not been consumed by the application.

(notice the mention of a *seekable file* ; usually your `stdin` is a terminal which is not a genuine disk file, and [lseek(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) would fail on the terminal)

BTW, [gets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html) is *deprecated* because *dangerous* (possible [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)!) and has [disappeared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output) from [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) standard. Use at least [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) and preferably [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) instead. Perhaps consider [GNU readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) library (which offers nice editing abilities).

Comment: The man page contradicts you: "For input streams, fflush() discards any
       buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has
       not been consumed by the application."

Comment: @Joni It's defined in some implementations, like Linux, but not in standard C.

Comment: That's why I point it out, @YuHao: maybe Basile should point the OP to the OS X man page instead of the Linux man page, since that's what they are using.

Comment: @YuHao @ Basile Starynkevitch But why it still doesn't discard buffer data as the manpage describes as to Linux? Woud you like to take a look at my question ?https://stackoverflow.com/q/55038401/5983841

Answer (score 4):

Because `fflush(stdin)` is `undefined behavior`.

The `fflush()` function is only meant to be used on `streams open for output`, not input. This method does seem to work with some C compilers, but is completely unportable! Thus, it should not be used.

Comment: Not exactly an [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) on *Linux*, according to the [flush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) man page on Linux. But it probably is an undefined behavior according to [POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/fflush.html)