# Scanf and subsequent line ignored in the output

Tags: c

In gedit, I wrote :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
char s[100];
char c;
printf("Enter a string :\n");
scanf("%s", s);
printf("Enter a character you don't want in the above string :\t");
scanf("%c", &c);
printf("%c", c);

printf("Your new string is :\n");
printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

The output I got in ubuntu terminal :
Enter a string :
abcd
Enter a character you don't want in the above string :  
Your new string is :
abcd

i.e., it waited for first scanf input, but completely ignored the second scanf and printf immediately after it (or may be not, because after "Enter a character you don't want in the above string :
", there is a nextline as you can see). The lines were not commented mistakenly, otherwise gedit would change it's color. Never saw anything like it before, completely puzzled......

Answer (score 2):

Nothing was ignored. But the second `scanf` read `\n` character that was left in the input buffer after reading `abcd`. That's why it didn't wait for another character from user.

You might want to read the string with `fgets` instead of `scanf`:

```
fgets(s, 100, stdin);
```

Also note that `scanf("%s"` will read up to whitespace, not the whole string.

Comment: Thank you. The same will happen with getchar() too. That means I'll have to use one extra scanf between too consecutive ones ?

Comment: You can make the second `scanf` to skip all spaces (and new-lines) before it reads the character: `scanf(" %c", &c);` (note the space before %c). Or you can skip everything until the end of line calling `getchar` in a loop. It depends on which input do you want.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already - `scanf("%s", s);` is not consuming `\n` that is left in the buffer. You don't have to type `\n` actually, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> after writing a string. It will send **EOT** character which tells console to pass input to program.

### Solution

Easiest way is to add space in scanf as follows:

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

From scanf documentation:

> White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string match any amount of >white space, including none, in the input.

### fflush

You should NOT use `fflush(stdin);` since it is documented as working on *output* streams, not on input ones.

Answer (score 0):

Use **getchar()** to deal with the **\n** in the input.

So **getchar()** will take **\n** as input and **scanf()** will take your input. 
Check out below

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    char s[100];
    char c;
    printf("Enter a string :\n");
    scanf("%s", s);
    printf("Enter a character you don't want in the above string :\t");

    char d = getchar();      //Takes the extra newline (\n) character as input

    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf("%c", c);

    printf("Your new string is :\n");
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

Comment: A difficultly with this approach occurs with input like "abc def".  `s` will first have the value "abc", `d` will take on the value of `' '` and then `s` will have then value "def".

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
fflush(stdin);
```

After

```
scanf("%s", s);
```

Inspired already explained why you need to do that.

Comment: That is undefined behaviour

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812749/why-fflushstdin-does-not-remove-buffer-stdin/20812756#20812756

Comment: Thanks AJ. now it's clear.