# Disallow input at certain times

Tags: c, input, scanf

I have got a text based game in c that uses scanf.

There are a few times when the player is supposed to type in things, however, while he isn't, the cursor stays in the game, letting the user type in anything he wants, which ruins future scanfs and the story.

Is there a way to disallow input unless there is a scanf waiting for a response?

Comment: What operating system is this working on?

Comment: mac, however I would prefer if it would work on all systems

Comment: Have you tried flushing stdin before calling scanf()?

Comment: @Nunchy: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined in C, and useless even where defined.

Comment: is getche() what you are looking for?

Comment: no, can you please show me the script to do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812749/why-fflushstdin-does-not-remove-buffer-stdin

<- fflush(stdin) was not working on a mac in this case. It's made for flushing output streams.

Comment: can you show how you're calling the scanf in your program?

Comment: What exactly is the program doing when he is not supposed to enter anything?

Comment: printing lines of dialogue and if statements

Comment: @crassfh can you show how you're calling your scanf?

Comment: scanf("%[^\n]%*c", name);

Comment: @crassfh just try scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", name); //the space is important

Comment: didn't work. The issue isn't the scanf, its just at anytime the player can press the game and type

Comment: @crassfh basically you want to give an input while your program is still running. Multithreading?

Comment: No, i don't want the user to be able to give an input unless specifically told to using scanf. @Ilaya Raja S

Comment: Look up `ncurses`.

Answer (score 9):

I think it would be helpful to step back and think about all the moving parts that exist in the execution environment of your program.

When executed, your program becomes a distinct process running in the multitasking environment of the OS. The terminal is a separate process with an associated GUI window, and which may be running locally or remotely (e.g. someone could theoretically run your game from a remote location by connecting over a network via ssh). The user interacts with the terminal program through their keyboard and screen.

Now, it is actually the terminal process (working closely with the OS kernel) that is responsible for most of the nuances of user input. It is the terminal that prints just-typed characters to its GUI window as soon as it receives them, and it is the terminal that maintains an input buffer of characters that have been typed but that have not yet been read by a foreground process.

Conveniently, terminals allow their behavior to be controlled by a set of configuration settings, and these settings can be changed programmatically during the run-time of the connected program. The C-level API that we can use to read and write these settings is called [termios](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios).

There's a great article on terminals I highly recommend: [The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/). For the purposes of this question, the section **Configuring the TTY device** is most useful. It doesn't demonstrate the termios library directly, but shows how to use the [`stty`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty) utility which uses the termios library internally.

(Note that, although the links I've been giving so far are focused on Linux, they are applicable to all Unix-like systems, which includes Mac OS X.)

---

Unfortunately there's no way to completely "disallow" input with a single switch, but we can achieve the same effect by toggling a couple of terminal settings and manually discarding buffered input at the right times.

The two terminal settings we need to concern ourselves with are `ECHO` and `ICANON`. Both settings are normally on by default.

By turning off `ECHO`, we can prevent the terminal from printing just-typed characters to the terminal window when it receives them. Hence, while the program is running, any characters the user types will seem to be ignored completely, although they will still be buffered internally by the terminal.

By turning off `ICANON`, we ensure that the terminal will not wait for an enter keypress to submit a complete line of input before returning input to the program, e.g. when the program makes a `read()` call. Rather, it will return whatever characters it currently has buffered in its internal input buffer, thereby making it possible for us to discard them immediately and carry on with execution.

The full process will look like this:

**1:** Disable input, meaning turn off `ECHO` and `ICANON`.

**2:** Run some gameplay with output, not requiring any user input.

**3:** Enable input, meaning discard any buffered terminal input and then turn on `ECHO` and `ICANON`.

**4:** Read user input.

**5:** Repeat from step 1. Subsequent gameplay can now make use of the latest user input.

There is a complication in step 3 related to discarding buffered input. We can implement this discarding operation by simply reading input from stdin via `read()` with a fixed-length buffer until there's no more input to be read. But if there's no input ready to be read *at all* for the discarding operation, then the first call would block until the user types something. We need to prevent this blocking.

I believe there are two ways this could be done. There's such a thing called a non-blocking read, which can be set up with termios or [`fcntl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) (or by opening a second file descriptor to the same endpoint with the `O_NONBLOCK` flag, I think) which would cause `read()` to return immediately with `errno` set to `EAGAIN` if it would block. The second way is to poll the file descriptor with [`poll()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) or [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) to determine if there's data ready to be read; if not, we can avoid the `read()` call completely.

Here's a working solution that uses `select()` to avoid blocking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

struct termios g_terminalSettings; // global to track and change terminal settings

void disableInput(void);
void enableInput(void);

void discardInputBuffer(void);
void discardInputLine(void);

void setTermiosBit(int fd, tcflag_t bit, int onElseOff );
void turnEchoOff(void);
void turnEchoOn(void);
void turnCanonOff(void);
void turnCanonOn(void);

int main(void) {

    // prevent input immediately
    disableInput();

    printf("welcome to the game\n");

    // infinite game loop
    int line = 1;
    int quit = 0;
    while (1) {

        // print dialogue
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            printf("line of dialogue %d\n",line++);
            sleep(1);
        } // end for

        // input loop
        enableInput();
        int input;
        while (1) {
            printf("choose a number in 1:3 (-1 to quit)\n");
            int ret = scanf("%d",&input);
            discardInputLine(); // clear any trailing garbage (can do this immediately for all cases)
            if (ret == EOF) {
                if (ferror(stdin)) { fprintf(stderr, "[error] scanf() failed: %s", strerror(errno) ); exit(1); }
                printf("end of input\n");
                quit = 1;
                break;
            } else if (ret == 0) { // invalid syntax
                printf("invalid input\n");
            } else if (input == -1) { // quit code
                quit = 1;
                break;
            } else if (!(input >= 1 && input <= 3)) { // invalid value
                printf("number is out-of-range\n");
            } else { // valid
                printf("you entered %d\n",input);
                break;
            } // end if
        } // end while
        if (quit) break;
        disableInput();

    } // end while

    printf("goodbye\n");

    return 0;

} // end main()

void disableInput(void) {
    turnEchoOff(); // so the terminal won't display all the crap the user decides to type during gameplay
    turnCanonOff(); // so the terminal will return crap characters immediately, so we can clear them later without waiting for a LF
} // end disableInput()

void enableInput(void) {
    discardInputBuffer(); // clear all crap characters before enabling input
    turnCanonOn(); // so the user can type and edit a full line of input before submitting it
    turnEchoOn(); // so the user can see what he's doing as he's typing
} // end enableInput()

void turnEchoOff(void) { setTermiosBit(0,ECHO,0); }
void turnEchoOn(void) { setTermiosBit(0,ECHO,1); }

void turnCanonOff(void) { setTermiosBit(0,ICANON,0); }
void turnCanonOn(void) { setTermiosBit(0,ICANON,1); }

void setTermiosBit(int fd, tcflag_t bit, int onElseOff ) {
    static int first = 1;
    if (first) {
        first = 0;
        tcgetattr(fd,&g_terminalSettings);
    } // end if
    if (onElseOff)
        g_terminalSettings.c_lflag |= bit;
    else
        g_terminalSettings.c_lflag &= ~bit;
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&g_terminalSettings);
} // end setTermiosBit()

void discardInputBuffer(void) {
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set rfds;
    while (1) {
        // poll stdin to see if there's anything on it
        FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        FD_SET(0,&rfds);
        tv.tv_sec = 0;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;
        if (select(1,&rfds,0,0,&tv) == -1) { fprintf(stderr, "[error] select() failed: %s", strerror(errno) ); exit(1); }
        if (!FD_ISSET(0,&rfds)) break; // can break if the input buffer is clean
        // select() doesn't tell us how many characters are ready to be read; just grab a big chunk of whatever is there
        char buf[500];
        ssize_t numRead = read(0,buf,500);
        if (numRead == -1) { fprintf(stderr, "[error] read() failed: %s", strerror(errno) ); exit(1); }
        printf("[debug] cleared %d chars\n",numRead);
    } // end while
} // end discardInputBuffer()

void discardInputLine(void) {
    // assumes the input line has already been submitted and is sitting in the input buffer
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
} // end discardInputLine()
```

I should clarify that the `discardInputLine()` feature I included is completely separate from the discarding of the input buffer, which is implemented in `discardInputBuffer()` and called by `enableInput()`. Discarding of the input buffer is an essential step in the solution of temporarily disallowing user input, while discarding the remainder of the input line that is left unread by `scanf()` is not exactly essential. But I think it does make sense to prevent residual line input from being scanned on subsequent iterations of the input loop. It's also necessary to prevent infinite loops if the user entered invalid input, so for that reason we can probably call it essential.

Here's a demo of me playing around with the input:

```
welcome to the game
line of dialogue 1
line of dialogue 2
line of dialogue 3
[debug] cleared 12 chars
choose a number in 1:3 (-1 to quit)
0
number is out-of-range
choose a number in 1:3 (-1 to quit)
4
number is out-of-range
choose a number in 1:3 (-1 to quit)
asdf
invalid input
choose a number in 1:3 (-1 to quit)
asdf 1 2 3
invalid input
choose a number in 1:3 (-1 to quit)
0 1
number is out-of-range
choose a number in 1:3 (-1 to quit)
1 4
you entered 1
line of dialogue 4
line of dialogue 5
line of dialogue 6
choose a number in 1:3 (-1 to quit)
2
you entered 2
line of dialogue 7
line of dialogue 8
line of dialogue 9
[debug] cleared 256 chars
[debug] cleared 256 chars
[debug] cleared 256 chars
[debug] cleared 256 chars
[debug] cleared 256 chars
[debug] cleared 256 chars
[debug] cleared 256 chars
[debug] cleared 238 chars
choose a number in 1:3 (-1 to quit)
-1
goodbye
```

During the first triplet of dialogue I typed 12 random characters which were discarded afterward. Then I demonstrated various types of invalid input and how the program responds to them. During the second triplet of dialogue I didn't type anything, so no characters were discarded. During the final triplet of dialogue I quickly pasted a large block of text into my terminal several times (using a mouse right-click, which is a quick and easy shortcut for pasting into my particular terminal), and you can see it discarded all of it properly, taking several iterations of the `select()`/`read()` loop to complete.

Comment: ok, thank you for the long response. I understand what you said above and below your code. However looking at the code itself I lost what the actual functions where doing. Please make a simplified version of your code, or at least comment it a bit more thoroughly and I'll accept it.

Comment: @crassfh Please let me know specifically what is not clear, and I'll explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux and HP-UX machines, use

#### to disable display of inputs from keyboard on terminal

```
stty -echo
```

#### to enable display of inputs from keyboard on terminal

```
stty echo
```